# Wi-Fi internet drops when switching rooms despite signal strength staying strong

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, wireless-router

I'm trying to use the internet from both my phone and laptop. In the room where the router is located, both my devices can use the internet. When I go to the next room over, both my devices can use the internet, although my phone loses a bar of signal strength. When I finally get to the room where I want to use the internet, my phone only has 1 or 2 bars of signal strength while my laptop still has full signal strength. However, I cannot access the internet at all in this room.

I'm two rooms away going through two solid wooden doors. Why is it that my laptop can still register a full signal strength and still get no internet? Can I fix this issue without a Wi-Fi extender?

When I am one floor below the room, my devices also get full signal strength to the router, however, I still cannot get internet access.

Comment: What operating system is running on the laptop?

Comment: @moonpoint MacOS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: don't fail onto the strength bar thing - the problem with this thing is that it only shows teh signal strength in one direction namly from router/accesspoint to your device in fact the are two directions this one and the one in the other direction most of the time when people having issues with connectivity although it shows good signal strenght the return way which has no indication icon is somewhat weak or scrambled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you in an apartment building, or are other houses very close to yours? When you move to the other rooms you may be picking up increased interference from other people's WiFi setups. The "signal strength" indicator in your laptop or phone usually doesn't show signal *quality*, just a "raw" signal strength, which doesn't take interference into account.

There are WiFi survey apps that you can get for your phone that will show all of the nearby WiFi networks, which channels they're on , and their relative signal strengths. These may suggest a different channel to use. Moving from 2.4 GHz to 5 GHz may help if you can do it. (Yes, 5 GHz doesn't penetrate walls very well - but far fewer people are using it.)

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using Mac OS, it is easy to check if you are on the recommended/best channel of 2.4 GHz before moving to 5 GHz. Additionally, not all devices/routers support 5 GHz and hence changing channels before changing frequencies is worth a shot.

First, check what channel your router is using. To do this, hold the option key and while doing so click on wifi symbol (usually on the top right of the screen on mac)

Next, check which channel is best for 2.4 GHz or 5 GHz: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLrlnYxksR8

See if this channel matches with what is being used by your router.

If yes, 
login to the homepage of your router and try changing to 5 GHz. 
If not,
login to the homepage of your router change to the recommended/best channel.

As an example, here's how you change the frequency/channel in a tp-link router: https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/2292/

Changing channels worked for me without having to change frequencies.